# How do I sum quantities in a repeating section?

Tags: cognito-forms

I have a quantity field in a repeating section.  I need to determine the total of that field outside of the section.  How do I sum up the quantity of items inside the repeating section in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com)

The easiest way to total up the quantity across all items in a repeating section is to leverage a calculation field to sum up the total.

For example, if you have a repeating section called "Products" and within each item you have a number field called "Quantity", you can create a calculation field outside of the repeating section. The calculation would simply be `=Products.Sum(Quantity)`. Make sure to set the Type of the calculation field to be "Number" so that the value is formatted correctly.[image]

I've included a screen shot a basic form that illustrates this setup.

You can also find this, and other powerful calculations in our help documentation at: [http://help.cognitoforms.com/calculations-overview](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/2/calculations), check out the section on "Working with Repeating Sections".